# Javafx update tableview on Checkbox change

Tags: java, checkbox, javafx, tableview, listener

I have an huge amount of data which i display with TableView in JavaFX. With help of [JavaFX 8 Sortung Filtering](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-tableview-sorting-filtering/) i was able to implement the filter depending on the input (TextField). There are only a few different states which a entry is able to have, so i want to make a quickselect with Checkboxes.
For example: The user want to see all rows with state "In Progress" or "Completed". So he checks the two checkboxes with the specific states.

How do I have to implement the specific Listener, that the TableView is going to show only the filtered data?

My code so far:

```
ChangeListener<Boolean> cbStateChangeListener = new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {  
    @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov, Boolean old_val, Boolean new_val) {
            if (new_val){
               
            }
        }
    };
```

How to proceed in the if-statement?

Answer (score 1):

Re-apply the filling of your view using the current state of the check boxes?

Comment: That's probably not a very good approach. Since the OP is already using a `FilteredList`, it will be more efficient just to change the predicate in the filter. Repopulating the list from scratch will also lose important state in the table, such as selection.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply bind the `predicate` property of `FilteredList` to a binding with the selected properties as dependencies.

Maybe you'll be able to optimize this, use less objects ect., however probably [you aren't gonna need that.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren't_gonna_need_it)

```
private Predicate<MyItemType> createPredicate() {
    ...
}
```

```
filteredList.predicateProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(this::createPredicate, checkBox1.selectedProperty(), checkBox2.selectedProperty(), ...));
```

BTW: It may be helpful to use `Predicate.or` to combine the `Predicate`s associated with each selected `CheckBox`.